# How to convert positive numbers to negative in Python?

Tags: python, numbers, negative-number

I know that `abs()` can be used to convert numbers to positive, but is there somthing that does the opposite?

I have an array full of numbers which I need to convert to negative:

```
array1 = []
arrayLength = 25
for i in range(arrayLength):
   array1.append(random.randint(0, arrayLength)
```

I thought perhaps I could convert the numbers as they're being added, not after the array is finished. Anyone knows the code for that?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Thanks, I wrote this code ages ago when I was a total rookie. It's fixed now :)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

If you want to force a number to negative, regardless of whether it's initially positive or negative, you can use:

```
    -abs(n)
```

Note that integer `0` will remain `0`.

Answer (score 20):

`-abs(n)` is a really good answer by Tom Karzes earlier because it works whether you know the number is negative or not.

If you *know* the number is a positive one though you can avoid the overhead of a function call by just taking the negative of the variable:

```
-n
```

This may not matter much at all, but if this code is in a hot loop like a gameloop then the overhead of the function call will add add up.

```
>>> timeit.timeit("x = -abs(y)", setup="y = 42", number=5000)
0.0005687898956239223
>>> timeit.timeit("x = -y", setup="y = 42", number=5000)
0.0002599889412522316
```

Comment: Good call @TomKarzes! I updated my answer to reflect your suggestion.

Comment: This is a really interesting point of view

Answer (score 5):

I believe the best way would be to multiply each number by -1:

```
def negativeNumber(x):
    neg = x * (-1)
    return neg
```

Answer (score 3):

You are starting with positive numbers, so just use the unary `-` operator.

```
arrayLength = 25
array1 = [-random.randint(0, arrayLength) for _ in arrayLength]
```

Answer (score -3):

This will also go good

```
import random
array1 = []
arrayLength = 25
for i in range(arrayLength):
   array1.append((random.randint(0, arrayLength)*-1))
```